# How can I use multiple accounts with Telegram?

Tags: applications, 4.4-kitkat, accounts, instant-messaging, telegram

There is a question [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/718912/244993) but that is for Ubuntu on PC.
I have the same question for an android device.

> Is there a way to have two copies of telegram app in Android each with
>   a different account?

I'm using the version **Kitkat 4.4**.

Comment: [Parallel Space](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lbe.parallel.intl) is often quoted to be preferred app for running two copies of same app. Be aware that there are permissions issues with this app. I never used it but you may like to try. If it works , let me know to post as an answer

Comment: @ beeshyams thanks and what about app cloner?  do you know anything?

Comment: Sorry. No idea about that app

Comment: Have you tried Disa unified messenger im with telegram plugin, I have used app cloner but not with telegram, so there are chances it may or may not work, generally it won't for applications that use Google play  services.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Parallel Space app. Using this app, you can run more than one copy of almost any app. Here is a link to the app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lbe.parallel.intl

Comment: seems it's the best choice but the problem is i'm living in Iran and I can't buy apps on Google Play (because iranians don't have access to international credit cards) and I just can download free apps. It seems that no free app can do the task completely. Thanks any way

Comment: Parallel Space is not a completely paid app, it offers in-app purchases. Do you really have to purchase this app for installing it in Iran? Because for me, it's not so. I can download it without purchasing.

Comment: You can get the apk of app from reliable source and sideload

Comment: @AnubhavDas Google play store says that the app is not compatible with my device. I don't know. maybe it would be downloadable but since I can't purchase, I can;t have access to all the functionalities

Comment: @beeshyams  what do you mean?

Comment: I'll see if I can download the free app and if it's enough to fit my needs

Comment: @sepideh If Google Play Store says that the app is not compatible for your device, it means that the app is not compatible with the version of android you're using, i.e. KitKat 4.4 & it has nothing to do with the pricing of the app.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR: It's available officially.**

From version **4.7 of Telegram** (December 30, 2017) [it's available officially in the Android app](https://telegram.org/blog/themes-accounts#multiple-accounts).

> ### Multiple accounts
>
> The Android app already supported multiple themes, so it had to go further with **4.7** by supporting **multiple accounts**. You can add up to three accounts with different phone numbers to your Telegram app, and then quickly switch between them from the side menu. Notifications will keep coming from all accounts, unless you change this in the Notification settings.
>
> [image]